How to Successfully Integrate JioMeet API for Scheduling Meetings?
I'm currently integrating the JioMeet API into my application and I'm encountering an issue despite providing a valid token and App Secret Key. Here's the request I'm making:
POST /api/platform/v1/recordings/isrecording
Host: jiomeetpro.jio.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer[Token]
Cookie: GCLB=CMbA4eeeoYmWQxAD
Content-Length: 35

HTTP Method: POST
URL: https://jiomeetpro.jio.com/api/platform/v1/recordings/isrecording
Headers:
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [JWT Token Here]
JSON Body:
{
"jiomeetId": "9876543210"
}
Response Received:
{ "customCode": 404, "message": "BADREQUEST", "errors": "No App Found!" }

Despite providing a valid token and App Secret Key, I'm consistently receiving an unauthorized error. I've double-checked the token and key, and they seem to be correct.
Question:
Has anyone successfully integrated the JioMeet API into their application? If so, could you provide guidance on how to troubleshoot this unauthorized error despite providing valid credentials? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
I tried to consume the JioMeet API according to the provided documentation. Specifically, I sent a request expecting to receive a response indicating the status of a recording, with a JSON object structured like this:
{
"recordingStatus": true
}
